# Change directories in shell scripts with string variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I have a series of directories that are only different by a numerical tag.

```
arr=(0 1 2 3)
i=0
while [ $i -le ${arr}]
do
  dir="~Documents/seed" 
  dir+=${arr[i]}
  echo $dir #works
  cd dir #directory not found
  #do other things#
done
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: is there a slash missing before `Documents`?

Comment: You probably want `[ $i -lt ${#arr[@]} ]` in line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be easier:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in ~/Dcouments/seed*
do
   if [ -d "$d" ]; then
      echo $d
   fi
done
```

**Note:**

You have tarfiles in ~/Documents too (with names that also match the wildcard), so I have added an `if` statement that checks if it is a directory or a file and only reacts to directories.

Comment: Hi, `echo $d` only lists one of the directories.

Comment: Please run `ls -l ~/Documents` and post the output and I'll have another look for you.

Comment: Ok, I see what you have now and have updated my answer - it should work now.